# Contract Deployment on Remix in JavaScript VM pending indefinitely

Tags: remix, remix-tests

https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=6082

I'm writing code along with this YT tutorial to learn Solidity with Remix. I cannot deploy the contract, it shows "creation of SimpleStorage pending..." in the console without changing for a long time.

The course instructor uses pragma solidity =>0.6.0 >0.9.0; at first then switches to ^0.6.0. Both of these give me errors saying that the compiler version isn't correct or compatible, even if I choose one of the 0.8.0 versions.

Once I switched to ^0.8.0 it worked, but this is probably *not* best practices and what I want (to be able to be up to date and use any version older (but still in circulation) or recent (^0.8).

Has anyone else had this error and know how to fix the "indefinite pending contract deployment"?

Comment: What's the code used for the contract? Which network are you using for deployment? Does your account have enough ether to pay for the transaction?

Comment: The Code is literally what you see if you click that youtube link, network is rinkeby test, yes account has eth (im not that noob)

Comment: It will be much easier to answer if the question were self contained. In my case I don't have much free time to watch a video, I prefer answering questions that I can test immediately in remix. For those question that I've to type the code I'll skip them entirely.